# Print list 2 which is dynamic to list 1 at its end excel

Tags: google-sheets

How to make a Formula to Print list 2 in google sheet which is dynamic, to list 1 at its end in google sheet. Need to know the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a list 1 having numbers (dynaimcly changing) and to bring that at list 2 at its end last number at list 2.
list 1    list 2
3           6
4           7
6           8 
             3
             4
             6